# remove element from pointer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to figure out why I cannot delete elements from the dict array. Could somebody help me out? The function removeWord is working as it is supposed to when removing the last added word, but not when trying to remove some other word.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>   
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS 11

int clear(){
    while(getchar()^'\n');
    return 0;
}

int numberOfWordsInDict(char **dict){
    int i = 0;
    int c1 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS; ++i){
        if (dict[i] != 0){
            c1++;
        }
    }
    return c1;
}

void addWord(char **dict, char *word){
    int c1 = numberOfWordsInDict(dict);
    char *word1;
    if (c1 >= 0 && c1 < 10){
        word1 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(word)+1));
        dict[c1] = word1;
        strncpy(dict[c1], word, strlen(word));
        dict[c1][strlen(word)] = '\0';
    } else if (c1 >= 10){
        printf("Dictionary is already full!\n");
    }
}

void printDict(char **dict){
    int i = 0;
    int c1 = numberOfWordsInDict(dict);
    printf("Dictionary:\n");
    if (c1 == 0){
        printf("The dictionary is empty.\n");
    } else if (c1 > 0 && c1 <= 10){
        while (dict[i] != NULL){
            printf("- %s\n", dict[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

void removeWord(char **dict, char *word){
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS; i++){
        if (strncmp(dict[i], word, strlen(word)+1) == 0){
            dict[i] = 0;// can only delete the last element of dict properly.
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char *dict[MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS] = {};
    char word[1024] = {};
    char command;

    while(1){
        printf("Command (a/p/r/q): ");
        while(scanf("%s", &command) == 1){
            break;
        }
        ;
        clear();

        if (command == 'a'){        // add word
            scanf("%[^\n]s", &word);
            clear();
            addWord(dict, word);
        } else if (command == 'p'){     // print dict
            printDict(dict);        
        } else if (command == 'r'){     // remove word
            printf("Remove a word: ");
            scanf("%[^\n]s", &word);
            clear();
            removeWord(dict, word);
        } else if (command == 'q'){     // quit
            break;
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS; i++){
        free(dict[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

example input:

```
a
dog
a
cat
a
apple
```

case 1:

```
r
apple
p
// output =
Dictionary:
- dog
- cat
a
uniform
p
// output =
Dictionary:
- dog
- cat
- uniform
// works fine
```

case 2

```
r
cat
p
// output =
Dictionary:
- dog
a
book
p
// output =
Dictionary:
- dog
// doesn't work as expected
```

Comment: OK, you have given us your code.  Now give us sample input, what you expect the output to be and what output you are seeing.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>   
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS 11

int clear(){
    while(getchar()^'\n');
    return 0;
}

int numberOfWordsInDict(char **dict){
    int c1 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS; ++i){
        if (dict[i] != 0){
            c1++;
        }
    }
    return c1;
}

int vacancy(char **dict){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS; ++i){
        if (dict[i] == 0){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void addWord(char **dict, char *word){
    int c1 = vacancy(dict);//It is not possible to use the registration number as an additional index.

    if (-1 != c1){
        dict[c1] = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
        strcpy(dict[c1], word);
    } else {
        printf("Dictionary is already full!\n");
    }
}

void printDict(char **dict){
    int c1 = numberOfWordsInDict(dict);
    printf("Dictionary:\n");
    if (c1 == 0){
        printf("The dictionary is empty.\n");
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS; ++i){
            if(dict[i])
                printf("- %s\n", dict[i]);
        }
    }
}

void removeWord(char **dict, char *word){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS; i++){
        if (strcmp(dict[i], word) == 0){
            free(dict[i]);//need free
            dict[i] = 0;// can only delete the last element of dict properly.
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char *dict[MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS] = { NULL };
    char word[1024] = { 0 };//forbids empty initializer braces
    char command;

    while(1){
        printf("Command (a/p/r/q): ");
        scanf("%c", &command);//%s buffer over run
        clear();

        if (command == 'a'){        // add word
            scanf("%[^\n]", word);
            clear();
            addWord(dict, word);
        } else if (command == 'p'){  // print dict
            printDict(dict);        
        } else if (command == 'r'){  // remove word
            printf("Remove a word: ");
            scanf("%[^\n]", word);
            clear();
            removeWord(dict, word);
        } else if (command == 'q'){  // quit
            break;
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS; i++){
        free(dict[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was in fact busy looking what is going wrong with my indexing in the addWord function. Indeed, using numberOfWordsInDict is not possible as with this some words were being overwritten. Thanks also for the other remarks, I will look around for them.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `printDict()` use

```
  while (i<MAX_NUMBER_OF_WORDS){  
       if(dict[i] != 0)
           printf("- %s\n", dict[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

instead of

```
  while (dict[i] != NULL){
        printf("- %s\n", dict[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

because even if you know if there are `c1` number of words, you don't know their location as in where those `c1` words are present.
Also change

```
  while(scanf("%s", &command) == 1)
```

to

```
  while(scanf("%c", &command) == 1)
```

since `command` is of `char` type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With your suggestion it is possible to print out all the remaining(not removed) words in dict. However, there was also a problem with the c1 indexing with calling the function numberOfWordsInDict when adding a new word after one was removed.